# Multipart download of SQLServer IMAGE type data

Tags: c#, sql-server, download

Some context first:
When you want to speed up downloading of a FILE over the internet you can make use of a multipart file downloader also known as a download accelerator.

Question:
I have a single zipped-file stored in a sql-server table of column type IMAGE. 
Is it possible to download that single IMAGE data (zip file) in multiple parts at the same time ?

To give you an example; Say I used two threads to download that single IMAGE data of 1000 bytes. Thread 1 would start downloading from index 0 and end at index 500 and thread 2 would start downloading from index 500 and end once it reached the end of the data.

Additional info:
If this is possible, I plan to use C# to develop an app to perform this multipart download of SQLServer IMAGE data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function to get sections of [IMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187993.aspx) data. For example you could use a stored procedure like this;

```
create proc dbo.GetImageData(@key int, @start bigint, @length bigint) as
begin

    select substring(MyImageValue, @start, @length)
    from dbo.MyImageTable
    where MyKey = @key

end
```

If you are going to use multiple threads to read a single IMAGE value I would expect it to saturate the connection capacity fairly quickly so I would do some real world testing before going too far down this route.

One last point, the IMAGE datatype has been deprecated for some time, you should investigate changing IMAGE columns to VARBINARY(MAX) if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Who would have known substring works on IMAGE data types.